# User belonging to the system admin profile Not able to send Email

Tags: email, email-alert

We have two users both belonging to the same profile(Sys Admin), But one user is able to send the email(Workflow- Email Alert) but the other user is not able to send the email, Both have same permissions and everything

Comment: Are you sending the email from an org wide address?

Comment: No I am sending an email to the same user

Comment: Not what I meant but I just checked OWA's are shared on profile level only.  Apologies for the confusion.

Comment: Are you sure the workflow is firing for the problem user?

Answer (score 0):

I understand like you are sending email to you. So sender email and receiver email will be same. If it is the case some email clients won't accept the email if sender and receiver email ids are same.